# Generic Kotlin factory to DRY constructor parameters

Tags: kotlin, generics, constructor, dry

I have the following simple class hierarchy.

```
abstract class B {
  abstract val o : Int
}

class D1 (m: Int, n: Int) : B() {
  override val o = m + n
}

class D2 (m: Int, n: Int) : B() {
  override val o = m * n
}
```

I need a "factory function" `f` that gives me instances of `D1` or `D2` by calling it as `f<D1>()` or `f<D2>()` with hard coded parameters, say `3` and `4`. The following doesn't work but illustrates what I need:

```
// won't compile; just demonstrates what I need
fun < T : B > f () : T {
  return T(3, 4)  // i. e. return T.constructor(m, n)
}
```

How to best accomplish this? Any DRY way is fine as long I don't have to repeat `3, 4` all over my code when I instantiate `D1` or `D2`

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do it is via reflection and reified type parameter:

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T : B> f(m: Int = 3, n: Int = 4): T {
    val constructor = T::class.constructors.first {
        it.parameters.size == 2 &&
                it.parameters.all { param -> param.type == Int::class }
    }
    return constructor.call(m, n)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for a comment follow-up. If I use a factory class rather than a function, then would it be possible to pass the desired T constructor as a parameter to the factory class constructor?  (I guess not because the specific T would be unknown when writing the factory class and so a constructor could not be supplied. Only the structure of the parameter could be supplied or remain hard-coded and the appropriate constructor could be located at factory construction time for use in subsequent calls to the factory member function.)

Comment: You can pass whatever you want into the factory class constructor, but what do you want to achieve? Since exact `T` is unknown at the moment of `Factory` creation, it still needs to be specified on the factory method call. Yes, you may do some caching of appropriate constructors for each `T`, but I believe it's better to do it lazily (on the first lookup of each `T`, not all at once on `Factory` construction).

Comment: By the way: `inline fun < reified T : AbstractGoogleJsonClient> make () : T =
  (T::class.nestedClasses.first { it.simpleName.equals("Builder") }.constructors.first().call(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(), GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), HttpCredentialsAdapter(cred())) as AbstractGoogleJsonClient.Builder).run { setApplicationName("younum-test"); build() as T }` works beautifully. Now I can invoke it as: ` val drive = make<Drive>()` and ` val activity = make<DriveActivity>()` Thanks!  (3 monstrous builder parameters were otherwise duplicated)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternate way without reflection, but you have to manually type out a line for each class you want to handle.

```
inline fun <reified T : B> f(): T{
    val m = 3
    val n = 4
    return when (T::class) {
        D1::class -> D1(m, n)
        D2::class -> D2(m, n)
        else -> error("Unsupported type ${T::class}")
    } as T
}
```

Comment: Almost equally correct, and, in fact, worked better for my specific situation as I needed to use the `<T>.Builder` nested class. I do feel that for others, likely in simpler situations, the earlier answer will be a better canonical reference, and I hope it will be better for the community to accept the other answer even though this is the one I ended up using? Thank you very much for the very useful answer!